# How can i execute a command using vim in Terminal?

Tags: bash, laravel, vim, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to install laravel and have been instructed to paste the following into terminal so that the laravel executable can be located in the system path:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Once in vim mode (really new to all of this if you couldn't tell already haha), i'm instructed to type the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vender/bin:$PATH"
```

My confusion is this: pressing 'Enter' doesn't submit this command, it just jumps to a new line in the Terminal. I googled this and it must be the dumbest question ever because i can't find an answer....how do i execute this command?? lol. Thanks for the help

Comment: You have to save changes in vim, exit vim and run command `source ~/.bashrc` to reload changes from `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Vim has 2 modes of operation. Normal and Edit.

Press `i` to enter edit mode then paste or type your command

Once done, to save and exit type `ESC` `:` `x` `ENTER`

To load in the changes to your current bash session from the command prompt run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You only need to do this once, as every time you start a new bash session your `~/.bashrc` script will be run

Vim is incredibly powerful but a bit of surprise if you are used to GUI editors. 
See
https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim
for a getting started guide

Comment: Add `source ~/.bashrc` to reload changes

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe add it on a separate line, for me the answer breaks command in 2 lines...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vender/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Beat me to it :D

Comment: I don't see how this answer answered OP's question. It doesn't explain how to execute a command in vim, it doesn't execute a command either... so -1 for now.

Comment: @Jack Do i type this in regular terminal or in vim?

Comment: @MichaelTrieb so far this answer won't help you to execute any command. read the comment under your question.

Comment: DON'T try to execute a command in vim from a script.  What I wrote is just to be a line in your script to replace the vim commands.

Comment: Code only answers may solve the original question, but having some explanation makes a much better answer as it helps others understand why this solves the problem.